# Python + CSV : Sum up Similar Values from a CSV columns

Tags: python, csv

**INPUT file:**

```
$ cat dummy.csv 
OS,A,B,C,D,E
Ubuntu,0,1,0,1,1
Windows,0,0,1,1,1
Mac,1,0,1,0,0
Ubuntu,1,1,1,1,0
Windows,0,0,1,1,0
Mac,1,0,1,1,1
Ubuntu,0,1,0,1,1
Ubuntu,0,0,1,1,1
Ubuntu,1,0,1,0,0
Ubuntu,1,1,1,1,0
Mac,0,0,1,1,0
Mac,1,0,1,1,1
Windows,1,1,1,1,0
Ubuntu,0,0,1,1,0
Windows,1,0,1,1,1
Mac,0,1,0,1,1
Windows,0,0,1,1,1
Mac,1,0,1,0,0
Windows,1,1,1,1,0
Mac,0,0,1,1,0
```

**Expected output:**

```
OS,A,B,C,D,E
Mac,4,1,6,5,3
Ubuntu,3,4,5,6,3
Windows,3,2,6,6,3
```

*I generated above output using Excel's Pivot Table.*

**MyCode:**

```
import csv
import pprint
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

with open('dummy.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        d[row['OS']]['A'] += row['A']
        d[row['OS']]['B'] += row['B']
        d[row['OS']]['C'] += row['C']
        d[row['OS']]['D'] += row['D']
        d[row['OS']]['E'] += row['E']

pprint.pprint(d)
```

**Error:**

```
$ python3 dummy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dummy.py", line 10, in <module>
    d[row['OS']]['A'] += row['A']
KeyError: 'A'
```

My Idea was to get the CSV values accumulated into a dictionary and later print it. However, I get above error when I try to add the values.

This seems like achievable with built-in `csv` module. I thought this was an easier one :( Any pointers would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems. The nested dictionaries don't initially have any keys set so `d[row[OS]]['A']` results to error. The other issue is that you need to convert column values to `int` before adding them.

You could use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) as values in `defaultdict` since there missing keys default to `0`:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

d = defaultdict(Counter)

with open('dummy.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    for row in reader:
        nested = d[row.pop('OS')]
        for k, v in row.items():
            nested[k] += int(v)

print(*d.items(), sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
('Ubuntu', Counter({'D': 6, 'C': 5, 'B': 4, 'E': 3, 'A': 3}))
('Windows', Counter({'C': 6, 'D': 6, 'E': 3, 'A': 3, 'B': 2}))
('Mac', Counter({'C': 6, 'D': 5, 'A': 4, 'E': 3, 'B': 1}))
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer your question exactly, as it is indeed possible to solve the problem using `csv`, but it is worth mentioning that `pandas` is perfect for this sort of thing:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.read_csv('dummy.csv')

In [3]: df.groupby('OS').sum()
Out[3]:
         A  B  C  D  E
OS
Mac      4  1  6  5  3
Ubuntu   3  4  5  6  3
Windows  3  2  6  6  3
```

Comment: +1. However, I would prefer `csv` for this job as it saves me from installing a new package which is not practical on the server I am working on.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? You can write the dataframe to csv file to get the desired format.

```
import pandas as pd
# df0=pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
# df0
df=df0.copy()
df=df.groupby(by='OS').sum()
print df
```

Output:

```
         A  B  C  D  E
OS                    
Mac      4  1  6  5  3
Ubuntu   3  4  5  6  3
Windows  3  2  6  6  3
```

---

```
df.to_csv('file01')
```

**file01**

```
OS,A,B,C,D,E
Mac,4,1,6,5,3
Ubuntu,3,4,5,6,3
Windows,3,2,6,6,3
```

Comment: +1. However, I would prefer `csv` for this job as it saves me from installing a new package which is not practical on the server I am working on.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer Makes sense. But if you have to do a lot of these csv tasks then `pandas` is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

You got that exception because for the first time, `row['OS']` does not exist in `d`, so `'A'` does not exist in `d[row['OS']]`. Try the following to fix that:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

with open('dummy.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        d[row['OS']]['A'] = d[row['OS']]['A'] + int(row['A']) if (row['OS'] in d and 'A' in d[row['OS']]) else int(row['A'])
        d[row['OS']]['B'] = d[row['OS']]['B'] + int(row['B']) if (row['OS'] in d and 'B' in d[row['OS']]) else int(row['B'])
        d[row['OS']]['C'] = d[row['OS']]['C'] + int(row['C']) if (row['OS'] in d and 'C' in d[row['OS']]) else int(row['C'])
        d[row['OS']]['D'] = d[row['OS']]['D'] + int(row['D']) if (row['OS'] in d and 'D' in d[row['OS']]) else int(row['D'])
        d[row['OS']]['E'] = d[row['OS']]['E'] + int(row['E']) if (row['OS'] in d and 'E' in d[row['OS']]) else int(row['E'])
```

**Output:**

```
>>> import pprint
>>>
>>> pprint.pprint(dict(d))
{'Mac': {'A': 4, 'B': 1, 'C': 6, 'D': 5, 'E': 3},
 'Ubuntu': {'A': 3, 'B': 4, 'C': 5, 'D': 6, 'E': 3},
 'Windows': {'A': 3, 'B': 2, 'C': 6, 'D': 6, 'E': 3}}
```

Comment: +1. I never realized the keys are empty in first place. May be because I had used `autovivification` in perl a lot. Now I understand what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

`d` is a dictionary, so `d[row['OS']]` is a valid expression, but `d[row['OS']]['A']` expects that dictionary item to be some kind of collection.  Since you didn't provide a default value, it will instead be `None`, which is not.

Answer (score 0):

This extends [niemmi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5043793/niemmi) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41363513/3657941) to format the output to be the same as the [OP's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1251660/slayedbylucifer) [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41363430/3657941):

```
import csv
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

d = defaultdict(Counter)
with open('dummy.csv') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    field_names = reader.fieldnames
    for row in reader:
        counter = d[row.pop('OS')]
        for key, value in row.iteritems():
            counter[key] += int(value)

print ','.join(field_names)
for os, counter in sorted(d.iteritems()):
    print "%s,%s" % (os, ','.join([str(v) for k, v in sorted(counter.iteritems())]))
```

**Output**

```
OS,A,B,C,D,E
Mac,4,1,6,5,3
Ubuntu,3,4,5,6,3
Windows,3,2,6,6,3
```

**Update:** Fixed the output.

Comment: Something is wrong in the sorting/joining in above code as the output is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to sort the counter.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your input file is called `input_file.csv`.

You can also process your data and have your desired output using `groupby` from `itertools` module and `two dicts` like the example below:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = list(k.strip("\n").split(",") for k in open("input_file.csv", 'r'))

a, b = {}, {}
for k, v in groupby(data[1:], lambda x : x[0]):
    try:
        a[k] += [i[1:] for i in list(v)]
    except KeyError:
        a[k] = [i[1:] for i in list(v)]

for key in a.keys():
    for j in range(5):
        c = 0
        for i in a[key]:
            c += int(i[j])
        try:
            b[key] += ',' + str(c) 
        except KeyError:
            b[key] = str(c)
```

Output:

```
print(','.join(data[0]))
for k in b.keys():
    print("{0},{1}".format(k, b[k]))

>>> OS,A,B,C,D,E
>>> Ubuntu,3,4,5,6,3
>>> Windows,3,2,6,6,3
>>> Mac,4,1,6,5,3
```